# Is Java ClassLoading SingleThreaded?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, volatile

While reading on Multi threading, I came to know that Singleton need to have double locking check and singleton reference declared as volatile so that

1. Synchronization overhead is avoided
2. Multiple Thread does not created multiple instances of Singleton class under consideration by accident
   Please refer this blog.
   http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2014/05/double-checked-locking-on-singleton-in-java.html

The questions in my mind are,

If the Class loading is single threaded why we care for multi threading issue?

A static initializer block happens to execute exactly once in application life cycle, then why not create a singletone using static initializer ?

Comment: In general, you should [ask multiple questions as multiple posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Class loading is [*not* necessarily single threaded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/cl-mt.html). Since Java 7, `ClassLoader`s can mark themselves as [parallel capable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#registerAsParallelCapable--).
2. Instantiating a singleton in a static initializer is fine. The main downside is that these initializations are [eager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Eager_initialization), as opposed to [lazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Lazy_initialization). This can be mitigated by the using the [initialization on demand idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom). However take note, it is possible to run a static intializer twice by creating a custom `ClassLoader`.

Comment: I went through the Java Language spec here:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html 
Like you said, Class loading is multi threaded, but since if subsequent thread sees that the class is already been initialized, it wont initialize that class again, as it is said in section 12.4.2. Detailed Initialization Procedure on the same URL.

Comment: @Nealesh You are correct. The standard `ClassLoader`s won't load the same class twice. However, you could create a custom `ClassLoader` that will always define a class from scratch, even if another `ClassLoader` has already loaded that class.

Answer (score 2):

It is true and you are right that the static initializer block happens only once. In fact, it is lazy; it will only be run when the class is actually needed. Therefore, one could simply and directly instantiate statically an object and have a getter for it. This is demonstrated using the « Initialization On Demand Holder idiom » :

```
private static class LazySomethingHolder {
  public static Something something = new Something();
}

public static Something getInstance() {
  return LazySomethingHolder.something;
}
```

See http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#dcl for more information. The page explains very well how it is an alternative to the double locking mechanism you referred to.